# When does Padme's & Anakin's relationship start?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, attack-of-the-clones, padme

As per the *Star Wars* movie *Attack of the Clones* (2002), Padmé says to Anakin:

> I've been dying a little bit each day since you came back to my life. ... I love you. ... I think our lives are about to be destroyed anyway. ... I truly, deeply love you.

Can anyone say from which time Padmé was in love with Anakin?

Comment: Padme was in love with Anakin, like, during the movie? I know it's horrible but if you pay attention you can see it. Or maybe you should be forgiven for not seeing it for the precise same reason.

Comment: im asking when she got the Love feelings for Anakin? 1st seen or later..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

She "fell in love" with him during the events of the movie.

- Their first meeting in AotC is their first meeting since separating a decade ago. This is the first time she meets Anakin after he is all grown up. At this point, Anakin is instantly infatuated with her but for Padme it's straight to the friendzone for him.
- When she returned to Naboo to retreat from politics for a while, Anakin was assigned to escort her while Obi-Wan runs off to start the Clone Wars. They will be alone with nobody but each other until the war starts.
- Throughout their stay in Naboo, Anakin shamelessly flirts with Padme and tries to break out of the friendzone and advance to the next base. Padme is subconsciously touched - her emotions are a mess, but she intentionally or subconsciously refuses to acknowledge it as love, choosing instead to let cooler heads prevail and not partake in violating Jedi rules nor enter into a work relationship.
- By the time they are preparing to be executed in Geonosis. Padme started to believe that she'll really die there - under the circumstances, what will you do to die with no regrets, however taboo it may be?

Padme started to feel attracted to Anakin while on Naboo, but she was in self-denial until Geonosis, when she finally sorted herself out and admitted to herself that she does indeed "love" Anakin.

Comment: Also, she's not like sand. Anakin hates sand.

Answer (score 2):

• When Padmé first meets Anakin since their 10 year absence, she's initially impressed with how much he had grown and how handsome he had turned out. But nothing more. She still saw him as a "that little boy she knew on Tatooine" still calling him Ani from time to time.

• On the refugee transport to Naboo Anakin and Padmé finally get a chance to talk. Padmé states that it must be very difficult being a Jedi and that you could not go anywhere or do anything you like, Anakin, very abruptly shifts the conversation into love. Padmé is a bit stunned but amused that he would mention love. For the Jedi were forbidden from it. Anakin's nerves crack a little bit when she gazes at him. Anakin reveals a side of himself that is very intelligent and romantic and she picks up on it. This is when Padmé first begins to "notice" Anakin. She makes a comment of how much he has changed but really telling him how handsome she thought he was.

• Standing by the lake with Anakin, Padmé is wearing her first informal dress that's very flowy, eye-catching with an open back, showing more skin than we have ever seen before. This dress speaks volumes to how she is feeling. She is comfortable around Anakin to reveal her skin around him and that she was physically attracted to him. As she reminisces on her happy childhood Anakin tried to forget his. It's then that Anakin subtlety touches her. First he strokes her hand, she allows it, then he moves his hand and gently strokes her back, this is a different kind of touch. It's very bold and very sexy. Anakin is sending a very clear message. He leans into her giving her plenty of time pull away, he kisses her and she kisses him back. Its safe to say she is very physically attracted to him at this point.

• Her attraction only grows over time but its not until he loses his mother she starts falling in love with him.

Answer (score -1):

For Anakin I think it was when he saw an "angel" walk into the shop. For Padmé, when she thought he was injured while showing off.